# Icons disappearing/reappearing, causing input lag

Tags: unity, 22.04, icons, dock

**Ubuntu 22.04 LTS / AMD / Wayland**

I have a problem that just started happening. Only *certain* icons in the Dock seem to disappear/re-appear every 15-30 seconds. Every time it happens, the mouse skips. I recorded the problem here:

[image: icon problem with foobar]

That is foobar2000, which is a Wine program. I am also using Dash to Panel in that clip. So naturally, I disabled all extensions to see if it was still happening. It was:

[image: Icon problem with foobar and OpenSnitch]

That second program is OpenSnitch, a linux-native firewall that I had as a deb package, then removed and reinstalled compiled from source, because I thought it would fix this problem

The only similarity I could think of between these two programs is that they both monitor connections. foobar monitors it's library folder and OpenSnitch is an application-level firewall.

Here's a still image of the second gif in which you can see what happens the moment the icons "disappear":

[image: still image of the foobar and opensnitch icons disappearing]

I don't know what to make of this. Would really appreciate some guidance.

Comment: Can you log in using X instead of Wayland just to see if it might be a Wayland thing?  I know my work tower was having similar issues when I was trying to run my apps under Wayland.  I switched back to X and have not had any issues since.

Comment: I just boot into an X session, and it's still happening unfortunately

Comment: I think I may have fixed it but I don't want to answer this just yet. I must have had a faulty USB extension cord plugged into my PC. I unplugged it and the problem seems to have resolved itself

Comment: If you feel that you have fixed it, you can write an answer below helping others that might experience the same issue.  Good find!  :)

Comment: I have not fixed it, the problem is back. Only this time it seems related to `tracker-fs-miner-3`, because it was stuck at a high CPU usage just as the problem came back. I disabled search indexing and the CPU usage problem is fixed, but now the problem I outlined in my original post is back, and no unplugging of cords has fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many weeks later, I finally solved the mystery by backing up then removing my ~/.config folder. As I started reconfiguring my applications one by one, I discovered that **appimagelauncherd** was the offending program. As soon as I launched my first AppImage, the icons started repainting again. So I checked System Monitor to see what I could do, and after ending the appimagelauncherd process the problem ceased, no more stutters.

I actually did this a couple of weeks ago, and I haven't had problems since, so I can safely conclude that it was AppImage Launcher causing the stutter issue. I don't know why unplugging that cord seemed to fix it for a while.

The moral of this story is that sometimes when you try to install certain software to make life easier, it actually ends up making things more complicated. If I want to have a desktop entry for an AppImage, I'll just make one myself from now on.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have fixed this on my own. I had a faulty USB extension cord plugged in to my PC which was also plugged into a game controller. I've had problems with this USB cord in the past, which I thought only caused problems on some USB ports, but after this I'm going to avoid that cord altogether.

As soon as I unplugged the cord, the application icons stopped disappearing, and the stutter was gone. The only reason I can guess for this being the cause of the problem is that maybe the USB connector was faulty, and my PC was trying to make a connection to it, but only partially succeeding. I've had this same cable plugged in to an external HDD dock in the past, and I got super slow speeds for any read/write operations done on those drives. Weird

So I guess the moral of the story is if you ever experience a problem like this, check your cables and USB ports.

**Update 2023-12-17**

The problem is back, and now I'm really out of ideas on what could be wrong. It also came with a new problem: tracker-miner-fs-3 was stuck at 100% CPU usage. I disabled search indexing altogether [using this guide](https://gist.github.com/vancluever/d34b41eb77e6d077887c), and that solved the CPU issue, but the lag stutter persists. I've been unplugging different cords to no effect.